# Values from checkboxes not working in Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have made a test app. When one or more checkboxes are selected and a button is clicked, the numbers corresponding to the checkboxes should get added up and displayed in a textView (which initially displays 0).

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        CheckBox rice = findViewById(R.id.rice);
        boolean ateRice = rice.isChecked();

        CheckBox egg = findViewById(R.id.egg);
        boolean ateEgg = egg.isChecked();

        CheckBox bread = findViewById(R.id.bread);
        boolean ateBread = bread.isChecked();

        int cal = countCal(ateRice, ateEgg, ateBread);
        String calString = String.valueOf(cal);

        Button calculate = findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            TextView numCal = findViewById(R.id.cal);
            numCal.setText(calString);
        });

    } //onCreate

    private int countCal(boolean ateRice, boolean ateEgg, boolean ateBread) {
        int calories = 0;
        if(ateRice){
            calories = calories + 20;
        }
        if(ateEgg){
            calories = calories + 50;
        }
        if(ateBread){
            calories = calories + 10;
        }
        return calories;
    } //countCal

}
```

But when I click the button, nothing happens and the textView keeps displaying 0. What should I do?

[(Here's how the app looks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKAwO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing all the calculation in OnCreate, on the initialization of the actvity, and not when the changes are occurring, that is where the listeners come in.

You need to put the countCal calculation in the listener:

```
  calculate.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            TextView numCal = findViewById(R.id.cal);
           int cal = countCal(ateRice, ateEgg, ateBread);
           String calString = String.valueOf(cal);
            numCal.setText(calString);
        });
```

You also need a listener for the checkBoxes, only when the item is checked/unchecked the values (ateBread) should be updated. Otherwise it will calculate based on the initial state of the checkbox
for example:

```
rice.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isChecked ->
ateRice = isChecked
}
```

Comment: Where should I add `setOnCheckedChangeListener`? In the countCal function or in onCreate?

Comment: In OnCreate method